# Selecting one of random posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, random

I want to make a plugin in wordpress like quiz but not with special questions. Only with posts. i will get 4 post tittle and 1 featured image between those 4 post. guests will select right title of featured image. i'm getting random posts with;

```
<ul>
<?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=4'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<li><p desc="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

but i couldnt solve how i will select randomly right answer and get it's featured image as a question.

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $arr = array();  
        $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=4');
        foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
        <li>
            <p desc="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>    </p>
            <?php $arr[ get_the_ID() ]; // store every post id in array ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php 
    $id = array_rand( $arr ); // choose one random post id
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id,'thumbnail' ); // get thubnail against id 
?>
```

Use this code and compare user selected post id to '$id' value.

Cheers!!!